# Binance Websocket API stuck on OPEN MESSAGE

Tags: python, binance, binance-api-client

I have this...

```
import websocket

SOCKET = "wss://stream.binance.com:9443/ws/ADABUSB@nav_kline_1m"

def on_open(ws):
    print('opened connection')

def on_close(ws):
    print('close connection')

def on_message(ws, message):
    print('received message')
    print(message)

ws = websocket.WebSocketApp(SOCKET, on_open = on_open, on_close = on_close, on_message = on_message)
ws.run_forever()
```

When I run it it sticks on OPENED CONNECTION and then does nothing??
Any ideas?

No error messages and I have left it for minutes!!

Cheers
Zak

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found this and it worked!
I am on a Mac...

***Spot on! removed ::1 from /etc/hosts and its connecting. localhost was resolving to ::1. Thanks for help.***

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

> No error messages

How do you know, you haven't defined the `on_error`-callback :) ?

Try adding it like below and see if it makes a difference (it does on my end):

```py
import websocket

SOCKET = "wss://stream.binance.com:9443/ws/ADABUSB@nav_kline_1m"

def on_open(ws):
    print('opened connection')

def on_close(ws):
    print('close connection')

def on_message(ws, message):
    print('received message')
    print(message)

def on_error(ws, message):
    print('error:', message)


ws = websocket.WebSocketApp(SOCKET, on_open = on_open, on_close = on_close, on_message = on_message, on_error = on_error)
ws.run_forever()
```

Comment: I've added that in and still just sitting there... :-/

Comment: I INTERRUPTED the process in the SHELL instead of RESTARTING the SHELL and got this error...


opened connection
error: 
error: on_close() takes 1 positional argument but 3 were given